# Media server without internet?

Tags: networking, usb, pi-3b+, media-server, software-recommendation

On my phone I have the Foobar2000 app which allows me to play music through media servers.

On my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ I connected a USB stick and set up MiniDLNA.

This works fine but I figured it requires an active internet connection on the Raspberry Pi and my phone connected to the same network.

Is it possible to make MiniDLNA work without internet or are there any similar options?

Comment: why would you require an internet connection if the two devices are on the same LAN?

Answer (score 0):

> requires an active internet connection on the pi and my phone connected to the same network

MiniDNLA does not require the former if by "internet connection" you mean something with access to the WWW ("internet" can be taken more broadly to refer to any IP based network, which would include two computers with an ethernet cable etc). But the latter -- a network connection with the phone -- is sort of a logical necessity (if Foobar2000 has a feature to get around this, which is pretty unlikely, then that would require the phone and the Pi connected to the internet proper).

So for example: You should be able to do this by running a hotspot on the phone and connecting the Pi to that, while configuring the hotspot to prevent any connection beyond the phone.<sup>1</sup>  You could also do it on a WLAN with no uplink (ie., a local wifi network not connected to the internet proper).

---

1. If your phone is not connected to the internet (eg. if you have no data plan or often leave data off), the hotspot will still work and you will still be able connect to the Pi with it.  You can do it the other way around too -- set up a hotspot on the pi and have the phone connect to that -- but it is much easier on the phone side and if you do sometimes connect the Pi to the net via wifi you probably would not be able to do that with the hotspot running, whereas a phone can (whether the hotspot and the net uplink can be both be done with wifi simultaneously depends on the phone).

Comment: I was looking for a solution that doesn't require WiFi / mobile data plan so I can play music from the pi through my phone

Comment: No, you would not need a mobile data plan. It's still not clear to me (and hopefully this is not too condescending) that you understand the difference between "wifi" and "the internet". To illustrate, presumably you have a wifi router at home from an ISP or have at least lived somewhere with one before. That router is connected by some kind of cable (probably ethernet or coaxial) to either a modem or something outside somewhere which provides access to the internet.  However, you could detach that cable (meaning, no more internet proper) and the wifi in the house will still continue to work...

Comment: ....Of course, nothing will be able to reach the internet, but the wifi connected devices in the house will still be able to connect to each other via the router, eg., if you have an NAS or DNLA server, those will still work.  Make sense?  The same logic can be applied to your phone's hotspot, I've left a footnote above about this.